# Extracting text from pdf using acrobat reader free

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, acrobat

I am trying to extract some text from multiple pdf using vba and acrobat reader free. Is this even possible?

I have added reference to the adobe reader type library 10, but the method "AcroPDDoc.GetText(i)" is not avialble. Is there a reference I am missing or is this a pro feature?

```
Sub ExtractPDFText()

Dim AcroApp As New Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim AcroAVDoc As New Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim AcroPDDoc As New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim numPages As Long
Dim text As String
Dim i As Long

'Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
'Set AcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

If  AcroAVDoc.Open("foo.pdf", "") Then
Set AcroPDDoc = AcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
numPages = AcroPDDoc.GetNumPages

For i = 0 To numPages - 1
    text = text & AcroPDDoc.GetText(i)
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = text

AcroAVDoc.Close True
End If

AcroApp.Exit
```

Comment: Re _0


I am trying to extract some text from multiple pdf using vba and acrobat reader free. Is this even possible?_ No, it's not.  The free version simply does not provide that functionality

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach, if you are using Office 365, is to use the built Power Query functionality to read data from PDF's.

This removes your outside dependency on Adobe Acrobat.

Using a basic PDF like this as an example.

[image]

Navigate to the **Data** menu and select **Get Data - From File - From PDF**

[image]

Select the file and click on **Import**.
As an alternate if the format between the PDF's is consistent, you could import all PDF's in a folder using Power Query.

[image]

Select the data to import from the PDF.
Click on **Load**.
If the data needs to be manipulated, click on **Transform Data** instead.

[image]

The data will be imported.

[image]

Recording the steps with the Macro Recorder gives you this VBA:

```
Sub Add_Query()

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table001 (Page 1) (2)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""C:\SO extracting text from PDF.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table001 = Source{[Id=""Table001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table001, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Heading 1"", type text}, {""Va" & _
        "lue 1"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table001 (Page 1) (2)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table001 (Page 1) (2)]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table001__Page_1___2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub

Sub Refresh_Query()

    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub
```